# MK8+CMC vs CCM8

Tags: field-recording, stereo, sound-effects-recording, ms, schoeps

For now my mic collection is basically limited to a CMIT5, and after I rented a CCM8 to combine an MS with CMIT for a job I fell in love with the sound. So I want to buy one, mostly for booming but sometimes on tripod.

My mic wishlist in long term is in constant changing, but consists of:

- 2x cmc6
- cmcxt(for sfx downing high sample rate purpose)
- mk41
- 2x mk4
- schoeps fig.8

And sadly will be a slow acquisition.

My current thinking on this:

**CCM8**

PROS:

1.very practical and lightweight for booming.

CONS:

Unsure

**MK8+CMC6**

PROS:

1. after I can buy 1x cmc6 with 2x mk4 instead of a stereo kit 2x cmc6 with 2x mk4.
2. in future if I buy a cmcxt to use it with a mk4 or mk41 I could buy another cmcxt to use with mk8 and make a ms with high frequencies..

CONS:

1. not so practical and lightweight as CCM8, and every weight plus gets heavier with time when booming.

Basically the pros of MK8 are related with future acquisition, and as I said earlier my wishlist is always in constant changing, mostly the priorities.. ( I really don't know if I really will buy a cmctx.. and if I buy it, if it's make sense to use a cmcxt for MS.. or how should result if I use cmcxt in a MS but only on Mid mic ( ex: cmcxt+mk4or41 with ccm8)

So the point of this question is **What are the pros and cons of buying a CCM8 or a mk8 with cmc6**??

Comment: Hi ORB - I have removed the bits that were entirely opinion based, and tried to clean up the formatting a little.

Comment: Question also asked here : https://www.gearslutz.com/board/so-much-gear-so-little-time/1113540-ccm8-vs-mk8-cmc6.html

Comment: Question also asked here: http://jwsoundgroup.net/index.php?/topic/28499-mk8cmc-vs-ccm8/

Answer (score 1):

As you are in the short term using the 8 figure mic with your cmit5, the size factor is not really to be taken into account (using a ccm with the cmit will require a large suspension and windshield, you might even have issues finding an appropriate suspension to make both capsules coincident). The answer might be different if you were looking to purchase two ccm series microphones, as there are very compact system for ms with ccm capsules.

I would therefore go with a mk 8 + cmc 6 as, as you have already noticed, this will alow modularity in the future.